# Two common neighbours for every two vertices

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph with the following property:

every two vertices has exactly two common neighbours.

How to prove that $G$ is regular (i.e. every vertex has the same number of neighbours)?

Comment: @Alex Ravsky , yes, thank you